# Limiting a station to only LAN access on Vigor DrayTek 2920

Tags: configuration, router, draytek, vigor

How can I configure a Vigor router (2920 in my case, but I suppose it's quite similar across models) to allow a station, defined by fixed IP or MAC address, to only communicate within the LAN and not to the outside web?

Answer (score 0):

I would block the IP via ACL in the Firewall options. 
Firewall >> Edit Filter Set >> Edit Filter Rule

Select the filter set you want the firewall to apply to (by default it Data Filter)

Click rule 2, then

Direction = LANDMZ/TR/VPN -> WAN 
Source IP = the IP you want to block
Destinsation = select any address
Service type = Any

Filter = Block Immediatley

Do not forget to tick the Check to enable the filer rule in the top left and again in the edit filter set.